# How to show that $T_k(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ is the only polynomial of degree $k$ with the specific properties?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a $k$-times continusouly differentiable function.

Let $x_0\in U$ be fixed.

The $k$-th Taylor polynomial of $f$ in $x_0$ is $$T_k(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)=\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_m=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)\cdot x_{i_1}\cdot \ldots x_{i_m}$$
Show that $T_k(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ is the only polynomial of degree $k$ such that $$T_k(0)=f(x_0) \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}T_k(0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)$$ for all $m\in\{1,\ldots , k\}$, $i_\ell\in \{1, \ldots ,n\}$ and $\ell \in \{1, \ldots , m\}$.

To show that $T_k$ satisfies these properties we just have to replace $x_i=0$ for all $i$ for the first property and for the second one we have to calculate these partial derivatives, right?

But how can we show the uniqueness?

$$$$

**EDIT :**

I am trying to show that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}T_k(0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)$$

Is it maybe as follows? \begin{align*}\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}T_k(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\left [\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_m=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)\cdot x_{i_1}\cdot \ldots x_{i_m}\right ]\\ & =\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_m=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\left (x_{i_1}\cdot \ldots x_{i_m}\right )\\  & =\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{m!}\sum_{i_1=1}^n \ldots \sum_{i_m=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)\cdot x_{i_2}\cdot \ldots x_{i_m}\end{align*} Or how do we calculate the partial derivatives?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124308/discussion-on-question-by-mary-star-how-to-show-that-t-kx-1-ldots-x-n-is-t).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looks a bit difficult to show from the given form of the Taylor series polynomial. I think it is preferable to regroup powers of distinct $x_i$'s. A multinomial (polynomial in $n$ variables) may be written in a unique way as:
$$ P(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum_{k_1\geq 0,...,k_n\geq 0} c_{k_1,...,k_n} x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n} =: \sum_{{\bf k}\geq {\bf 0}} c_{\bf k} {\bf x}^{\bf k},$$
with some obvious definitions of multi-indices and where only finitely many $c_{\bf k}$'s are non-zero.

From an algebraic point of view this defines the $c_{\bf k}$'s uniquely. But to see it is unique in an analytic fashion you may take derivatives, using Schwarz' theorem showing that the relevant partial derivatives commute.
For ${\bf q}=(q_1,...,q_n)\geq {\bf 0}$ you may  verify by inspection that:
$$ \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf x}} \right)^{\bf q} P({\bf x})_{|{\bf x} = {\bf 0}} =  
\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{q_1} \cdots  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)^{q_n}  P \right)(0,...,0)  = (q_1)! \cdots (q_n)! c_{\bf q}.$$
Writing ${\bf q !}=  (q_1)! \cdots (q_n)! $ this yields (in compact notation):
$$c_{\bf q} = \frac{1}{\bf q !} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf x}} \right)^{\bf q} P({\bf x})_{|{\bf x} = {\bf 0}} $$
which defines $c_{\bf q}$ uniquely. A Taylor polynomial is obtained by calculating the $c_{\bf q}$'s using $f$ instead of $P$ and up to some fixed total order, again defining the $c_{\bf q}$'s uniquely.

Comment: I haven't really understood what $q$ is at your calculation of $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf x}} \right)^{\bf q} P({\bf x})_{|{\bf x} = {\bf 0}} =  
\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\right)^{q_1} \cdots  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)^{q_n}  P \right)(0,...,0)  = (q_1)! \cdots (q_n)! c_{\bf q}$$ Could you explain that further to me?

Comment: An example might help: $n=2$, ${\bf q}=(2,3)$: ${\bf q !}=2! 3! = 12$, $(\frac{\partial} { \partial {\bf x}})^{{\bf q}} $ = $( \partial / \partial  x_1)^2 (\partial / \partial x_2)^3$.

Comment: So writting the Taylor polynomial in the above way helps us to show the uniqueness of a polynomial with the given properties, right?

Comment: Yes, it also gives you a formula with fewer terms and (relatively) easy to manipulate. To see that it is the same formula as yours you need to know about multinomial coefficients (look up e.g. in wiki).

Comment: To prove that the Taylor polynomial satisfies the relation $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}T_k(0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}f(x_0)$$ dowe use also the form you used above?

Comment: Yes you may do so. Note, however, that you will repeat some of the partial derivatives. For example if $m=5$ and $(i_1,...,i_5) = (1,1,2,2,2)$ then the derivative is $(\partial_1)^2 (\partial_2)^3$ which corresponds to my example right above. So you don't have to check for all permutations giving rise to the same derivative.

Comment: So we first have to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}T_k(x)$ and then we calculate that for $x=0$, or not? So you mean to write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_1}}}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{i_m}}}T_k(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{1}}}^{j_1}\ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial{x_{n}}}^{j_n}T_k(x)$$ ? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Very nice and gentle presentation. (+1)

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it suffices to look at derivatives of the 2nd form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! :-)

Comment: OK, hope you have succeeded with the multinomial coefficients?