# Level lines - Parametrization

Tags: analysis, parametrization

We consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2-1}{y^2+1}$$

Describe and draw the level lines $N_c$ of $f$ for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Determine for each connected component of each non-empty level lines $N_c$ a parametrization $\gamma_c:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

$$$$

I have done the following :

We have that $$f(x,y)=c \Rightarrow \frac{x^2-1}{y^2+1}=c \Rightarrow x^2-1=(y^2+1)c \Rightarrow x^2-cy^2-(c+1)=0$$

If $c=0$ then we have $x^2=1 \Rightarrow x\pm 1$, so we get the lines $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

If $c>0$ we have then $c=m^2>0$. So $x^2-m^2y^2-(m^2+1)=0 \Rightarrow x^2-m^2y^2=(m^2+1)$. We have $B^2-4AC=0-4\cdot 1\cdot  (-m^2)=m^2>0$. So it is the general equation of an hyperbola with axes parallel to the coordinate axes.

If $c<0$ we have then $c=-m^2<0$. So $x^2+m^2y^2-(-m^2+1)=0 \Rightarrow x^2+m^2y^2=(-m^2+1)$. The left side is always non-negative, so also the right side must be. So $1-m^2\geq0 \Rightarrow m^2\leq1 \Rightarrow -1\leq -m^2 \Rightarrow -1\leq c$. That means that is $c$ is negative then $c$ must be greater or equal to $-1$. If $-1<c<0$ then we have the general  formula of an ellipse. If $c=-1$ then we get $x^2+y^2=0$ which is the point $(0,0)$.

Is that correct?

How do we determine for each connected component of each non-empty level lines $N_c$ a parametrization $\gamma_c:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your level lines are correct, confirmed by the following 3D representation of surface $z=f(x,y)$ (these contour lines are projected on the bottom plane).

[image]

About parametrization, use the classical:

$$x=a \cos(t), y=b \sin(t)   \ \ \text{for ellipses and}\tag{1}$$

$$x=a \cosh(t), y=b \sinh(t)  \ \ \text{ for hyperbolas}\tag{2}$$

For example, for the ellipse $(E_m)$ with equation :

$$x^2+m^2y^2=1-m^2 \ \iff \ \frac{x^2}{\left(1-m^2\right)}+\frac{y^2}{\left(\frac{1-m^2}{m^2}\right)}=1$$

by comparison with $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, you get:

$$a=\sqrt{1-m^2}, \ b=\sqrt{\frac{1-m^2}{m^2}}$$

and use (1).

Same operation for hyperbolas.

Comment: What is your reaction ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! It is very clear now!! :-)

Comment: Do you maybe have an idea also for my other question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4136944/80708 ?

Comment: I will have a look. I am not certain to have an answer...